# Fail to load .php files with ajax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Instead of using jQuery here I am trying to use Javascript to load several .php files to
display data from the database according to the user's input. Below is an example of how my functions are like (and most of which are similar):

```
let userinput = document.getElementById("input");

button_1.onclick = function()
{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "ajax/highscore.php?q="+userinput.value, true);
    // send the "username" to $_POST['q'] defined in "highscore.php"
    // and then display the data according to the user's input

    xhr.addEventListener("load", (event) =>
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // display data accordingly }
    });
    xhr.send();
}
```

and below is a screenshot of the index in the server. "sample.html" is the page for displaying all the data.

[image: screenshot1]

However, when inspecting "sample.html", I cannot see the "ajax" folder loaded, nor any other .php files even when I changed the path "ajax/(   ).php" to "(   ).php". Could anyone explain why this will happen? (In the second screenshot because the parent folder contain my server's name so I covered it)
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Check the permissions of the folder and check if php (www-data) is the owner of the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser dev tools (the inspect method you are using) do not list files in your server folder. It only displays files used to load your `sample.html` page, like CSS, JS files directly referenced (with `<script>` tags, and so on), etc.

Your `.php` files might still work, if your javascript ajax method calls them accordingly and they are reachable by the user's browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me test if it is working

Comment: @SanaeKochiya — You've accepted this answer as a solution to your problem, but your comment makes it seem that you don't have a solution yet. Which is it?

Comment: @Héctor Paúl Cervera-García   Please check the updates. All blocks of my codes that apply ajax method is like the example shown above but nothing happen when I click "submit" button. By all means thank you for answering my question and now I will turn to another different problem.

Comment: @Quentin I just found out a new problem but the reason why I cannot see files for ajax is given by Héctor Paúl Cervera-García.